# What is the correct syntax for using NOT in a google sheets filter / match?

Tags: google-sheets

My filter function is almost there, but not quite. I want to display only those `rows` in `List1` one that are not in `List2`, based on the `email column` (c). This works without the `NOT` and it displays only the matches, so of course I need to add a `NOT` to display only those that do not match.

Here is my almost working filter thus far. I am getting an error with this though, from adding the `NOT`. How do I fix it?

`=filter(List1!A2:D199, NOT(match(List1!C2:C199,List2!C1:C11, 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, lol, I found the answer two minutes later. I love when that happens. I need to use ISNA instead of NOT. (Or at least, ISNA seems to work fine to get the output I need). So the filter with match becomes the following:

`=filter(List1!A2:D199, ISNA(match(List1!C2:C199,List2!C1:C11, 0)))`

This works. Yay!